# Seperation of concerns - Controlling 2 dependant entities by using a service?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, service

I have two services: `ProfileService` knows how to manipulate `Profile` models (laravel eloquent) and `ListService` knows how to manipulate `List` models. `Profile` has a one-to-many relation with `List`. Relations are defined in those eloquent models.

The question I have is about separation of concerns. I intend to let `ProfileService` only do stuff with `Profile` and `ListService` only with `List`.

What kind of design pattern or construction would I need to do that while respecting the following requirement?

- I want a `destroyProfile` method on the `Profile` object which can delete the `Profile` and cause its related `List`s also to be deleted.

I think I need a third service that `ProfileService` can use to delete both models.

Comment: Make another service / class / object use composition (add the two models as dependency) and do the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let the database handle the deletions?

```
    Schema::table('lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('profile_id');
        $table->foreign('profile_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('profiles')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: That would be an option. What i rather would like to do is use some kind of design pattern i am not yet familiar with. I think i need the mediator pattern, and i am trying to implement that to see if it works like i want.

The main reason why i don't want to let the database handle the deletions is that i expect more complex relations in the near future, that require more then just deletion of data.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, in that case, you'd want the Observer pattern. Listen for an event (Profile deleted), then handle the event (delete the related lists, etc.). https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events